# tSQL NOT IN Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, notin

I want to get the ID's of [interactions] table but these ID's must not equal to [EmailOUT] table. I couldn't write the query.

```
Select ID from EmailOut         
where ID NOT IN         
   (select ID from
    [172.28.101.120].[GenesysIS].dbo.interactions 
    where media_type = 'email'
    and type = 'Outbound')
```

something similar to this. I want Outbound Emails in Interactions table but these emails may exist in EmailOut table. I want to remove them. Outbound Email count about 300 but this query result should less than 300

Comment: Are your foreign and primary keys named exactly as mentioned? Interactions.ID vs EmailOut.ID?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems you should reverse your query, if you want to get the ID's of [interactions] table:

```
select ID from
[172.28.101.120].[GenesysIS].dbo.interactions 
where media_type = 'email'
and type = 'Outbound'
AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM EmailOut)
```

Comment: .. and you can also use the NOT IN without selecting, like this example snip where you check for integers :  not in (119, 138, 158, 165) Just to mention a way to test the operator

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM [172.28.101.120].[GenesysIS].dbo.interactions t2
WHERE t2.media_type = 'email'
    AND t2.[type] = 'Outbound'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM dbo.EmailOut t 
            WHERE t.id = t2.id
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

What about

```
select ID from [172.28.101.120].[GenesysIS].dbo.interactions 
where media_type = 'email'
and type = 'Outbound' 
minus
select ID from EmailOut
```